# Best deployment tool for windows application with custom requirements?

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment, wix

I am looking for a tool to deploy windows application. My requirement is that I should be able to control the creation of the files and folders in the program files. I need to add my custom actions and execute them before the installation starts.

In the setup deployment tool from visual studio, the application first gets installed and then the custom actions are run. But I need to be able to control these steps.

I am currently researching the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/). Can you please let me know whether WiX can be the solution. If yes, then what do I need to do to add my own steps for installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Wix is the best solution for you.  It has installer sequence like **Install UI Sequence** and **Install Execute sequence**.  Write your custom actions and schedule it in this sequence as per your requirement. If you schedule it before Install Initialize action, it will run before start the installation.

E.g. I schedule a Custom action to run before installation starts.

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallASPNET" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

 <InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="InstallASPNET" Before="InstallInitialize">ASPNETREGIIS AND (NOT Installed)</Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

You need to get clear understanding regarding this sequence. Please go through some material before going to start.
There is lot of resources to learn Wix. I used the below materials.

Online: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/
Book: [A Developer’s Guide to Windows Installer XML](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513724)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Wix is perfectly suited to what you need. Custom actions can be scheduled before the installation of files if required and Wix provides plenty of in-built functionality which may reduced the need for you to create your own custom actions.

The best place to start is the [official docs](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/main.htm) and if I was you I would read through the "how to guides" as they are a really good start.